# How to load xls file in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
package{

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ReadFile extends MovieClip { 
            var urlLDR:URLLoader;
            var urlR:URLRequest;

        public function ReadFile ():void 
        { init();}

        public function init ():void {

            urlLDR = new URLLoader();
            urlR = new URLRequest("ftpserver.xls");
//urlR = new URLRequest("Test.xls");

            urlLDR.load(urlR);
            urlLDR.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,f);
        }

        function f(e:Event){
            trace(e.target.data);
        }
    }//class
}//package
```

If you have any idea just come with that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your Problem? Do you get any errors? Try adding some more listeners to exclude the problems.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class URLLoaderExample extends Sprite {
        public function URLLoaderExample() {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            configureListeners(loader);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("urlLoaderExample.txt");
            try {
                loader.load(request);
            } catch (error:Error) {
                trace("Unable to load requested document.");
            }
        }

        private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);

            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
            trace("The answer is " + vars.answer);
        }

        private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("openHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
            trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this library? http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/downloads/list

Good luck,
Rob